# Function that returns named list in R

Tags: r

I want to create a function that interprets the arguments one inputs in it as a vector of characters that afterwards its applied as names for the list. Something like this:

```
list_with_names<-function(...){
  b<-list(...)
  names(b)<-c(as.character(substitute(...)))
  return(b)
}
```

Also have tried this:

```
list_with_names<-function(...){
  b<-c(...)
  x1<-0
  for (a in b) {
    x1<-x1+1
    a[x1]<-c(as.character(substitute(...)))
  }
  names(b)<-c(a)
  return(b)
}
```

however it just reads the first argument.

Comment: like this? `list_with_names <- function(...) setNames(list(...), c(...))`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `dplyr::lst`

```
list_with_names<-function(...){
  dplyr::lst(...)
   }
```

and test as

```
list_with_names("hello", "hello")
$`"hello"`
[1] "hello"

$`"hello"`
[1] "hello"
```